# Set Window KeepScreenOn flag in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin Forms to display a HybridWebView control from

https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms.Droid/Controls/HybridWebView/HybridWebViewRenderer.cs

The issue is I would like to set the KeepScreenOn flag, however the Window.AddFlags method cannot be called from a static context, but as far as I'm aware, there is no activity readily accessible

```
Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn);
```

In the Shared project, I have App.xaml.cs which calls:

```
MainPage = new Project_App.MainPage();
```

Which is then in MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var hybridWebView = new HybridWebView {};
    Content = hybridWebView;
}
```

And finally in the .Droid Project, I have HybridWebViewRenderer.cs

```
public class HybridWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<HybridWebView, Android.Webkit.WebView> {

    Android.Webkit.WebView webView = null;


    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<HybridWebView> e) {
            webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(Forms.Context);    
   }
```

I also have a MainActivity.cs in the .Droid project

```
[Activity(Label = "Project_App", MainLauncher = true]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity {
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn);
        LoadApplication(new Project_App.App());         
    }
}
```

However, putting Window.AddFlags in this file does not keep the screen active, and putting a breakpoint on this line never gets hit, however removing this entire file causes the app to fail to launch

Why is the breakpoint in the last file never hit, or alternatively, how can I get a reference to the activity so I can call AddFlags from a method in the HybridWebViewRenderer.cs class?

Answer (score 2):

> However, putting Window.AddFlags in this file does not keep the screen active, and putting a breakpoint on this line never gets hit

This `KeepScreenOn` flag needs permission `WAKE_LOCK`, to make this code working, we need to add this permission in our manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Testing on real device, works fine. For the issue that breakpoint doesn't get fired, it could be the problem with your Xamarin version, try to update your Xamarin.

> how can I get a reference to the activity so I can call AddFlags from a method in the HybridWebViewRenderer.cs class?

I guess that you didn't post all your code of your `HybridWebViewRenderer`, here for your question, you can create your method in the renderer for example like this:

```
public void Keepscreenon()
{
    var mainactivity = Forms.Context as MainActivity;
    mainactivity.Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn);
}
```

Comment: I'm doing some adjacent searching regarding FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON vs. wake locks. I see in the Android docs' guides that the `android.permission.WAKE_LOCK` permission only applies to actual "wake locks" and not the use of the FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON flag.

From https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock#screen

> The advantage of this approach is that unlike wake locks (discussed in Keep the CPU On), it doesn't require special permission, and the platform correctly manages the user moving between applications, without your app needing to worry about releasing unused resources.

Comment: Do you happen to know if there was a change in requiring the permission in the ~4 years since you initially responded here? I'm working on an old enough version of Android that I'm willing to believe anything's possible.

Comment: Apologies for possibly spamming this thread. This will be my last follow-up on this. Looks like there were changes to automatically-granted permissions starting in Android 6/API level 23. Referred to in Microsoft's guide at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/permissions?tabs=macos

> This guide discussed how to add and check for permissions in an Android device. The differences in how permissions work between old Android apps (API level < 23) and new Android apps (API level > 22). It discussed how to perform run-time permission checks in Android 6.0.